# Is $63\times63$ the largest matrix with no rectangles that have an even number of each $0-9$ digit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integers

I'm working on an algorithm that finds the largest rectangle with an even number of all 10 digits within a square matrix, e.g. for the 4×4 square on the left that would be this 3×2 rectangle:

```
4 8 6 5    - - - -
3 4 1 2    3 4 1 -
1 3 4 5    1 3 4 -
7 4 0 9    - - - -
```

because it has two of the digits 1, 3 and 4. Now, if you run the algorithm on large squares with random values, the average number of rectangles you have to check before finding one with an even number of all digits is around C(10,0) + C(10,2) + C(10,4) + C(10,6) + C(10,8) + C(10,0) = 512 (because a large rectangle with random values will have a probability of around 1/2 of having an even number of any digit, but only an even number of digits can be present an even number of times in a rectangle with an even number of cells).

The worst case, where you'd have to check all rectangles with an even number of cells, because none has an even number of each digit, quickly becomes huge:

```
    size            rectangles

   2 x    2                  5
   4 x    4                 64
   8 x    8                896
  16 x   16             13,312
  32 x   32            204,800
  64 x   64          3,211,264
 128 x  128         50,855,936
 256 x  256        809,500,672
 512 x  512     12,918,456,320
1024 x 1024    206,426,865,664
```

However, when running tests on random data, the highest number of rectangles I ever had to check for any size input was 13,862 for a 64×64 square, even after running the test 10 million times. So I started wondering whether a large square with no valid rectangles was actually possible, or whether there is a maximum size.

When trying to construct worst-case input, I automatically ended up using the sequence:

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5 ...
```

which is made by taking the sequence so far, repeating it, and adding 1 to the last number ([OEIS A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814)). The squares it produces (by copying the previous size square four times and then adding 1 to the right-most column and the bottom row) are:

```
0,1
1,2
```

```
0,1,0,2
1,2,1,3
0,1,0,2
2,3,2,4
```

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6
```

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8
```

At his point, if you repeat the 16×16 matrix to create a 32×32 matrix and add 1 to the right-most column and bottom row, the bottom-right cell would have the value 10; we can replace this with a 1 (but that's the only value that works):

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,9
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,9,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,1
```

Then, when going from 32×32 to 64×64, there are several cells in the right-most column and bottom row for which every value creates a rectangle with an even number of each digit. So the maximum-sized square without rectangles with an even number of all digits that you can construct with this method seems to be this 63×63 matrix:

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,9,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,9,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,1,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,9,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,9,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
```

Of course, I don't know whether this is the best or only way to construct squares with no rectangles with an even number of each digit, and I also don't know whether there could be non-systematic, more random solutions. So my question is:

> Can it be proven that 63×63 is the largest square which has no rectangles with an even number of each digit 0-9? And if not, is there a maximum size? And is there a way to construct larger squares?

---

As Peter Taylor pointed out in a comment, a rectangle with height 1 is limited to width 1023, because there are only 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 different even-ness signatures with 10 digits, so either one of them will be 0 (meaning there is a rectangle with an even number of all digits up to that point), or two will be the same (meaning there is a rectangle with an even number of all digits between them) . Using the same logic, you can prove that a rectangle with height 2 is limited to width 511. Trying this out with the sequence explained above gave these maximum widths:

```
         1: 1023
  2 -    3:  511
  4 -   15:  255
 16 -   63:   63
 64 -  255:   15
256 -  511:    3
512 - 1023:    1
```

The 1×1023 and 2×511 limit are certain. The other limits may just be limits of the method I'm using to create the examples.

---

*(Please feel free to change the tags; I was unsure which ones to use.)*

Comment: Or suggest a move to Math Overflow if necessary; I don't really understand the difference.

Comment: I don't think your 1/1024 heuristic sounds right: the evenness of the various digits are not independent variables.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right; I changed the code to find all rectangles, not just the largest one, and it does indeed find an average of 1/512 rectangles with an even count of all digits in large matrices. Which makes sense, because only an even number of digits can have an even count, so the possibilities are C(10,0) + C(10,2) + C(10,4) + C(10,6) + C(10,8) + C(10,10) = 512.

Comment: The answer to "Is there a maximum size?" is that there is. Consider a 1x1024 rectangle. Label (1-indexed) cell $2k$ by the set of digits which occur an odd number of times in the first $2k$ cells. Then either one of them is labelled with the empty set, and we have a witness, or two of them have the same label, and the range in between them is the witness. I don't guarantee that the bound is tight.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point. I guess that also means that all rectangles with an odd height are limited to width 1023, and all rectangles with an even height are limited to width 511.